# How to convert a query from bash to python?

Tags: python, bash, gitlab

I have following a query for deleting a pipeline from gitlab.

```
curl -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" -XDELETE  "$LINK"
```

How can I do the same thing using python and request module?

I tried something like this

```
delete_request = requests.delete(delete_url, dict(PRIVATE_TOKE=''")
```

But it does not work because of following error message

```
delete() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Although it should take 2 arguments according to 
[Doc](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_delete.asp#:~:text=Python%20Requests%20delete()%20Method&text=The%20delete()%20method%20sends,(file%2C%20record%20etc).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
delete_request = requests.delete(delete_url, headers={"PRIVATE-TOKEN": ""))
```